# Membrane cone effect?

Tags: bezier-curves

I'd like to achieve something similar to this (the mesh shown in the picture.  I don't need it to be rendered as wireframe.  Just need the mesh):
[image]

What I have in mind is that I have a plane, and I subdiv and deform it with a circle using something like the hook modifier.  I tried it and apparently the hook modifier doesn't work as I imagined.

In addition, I'd like to not only let the plane deform by a circle, but also by a custom curve.

Comment: For something like that mesh specifically, I think you could do that with loop tools add-on, decimate modifier, and wireframe modifier.

Comment: @Timaroberts, ok I don't need to make it wireframe.  But let me look into that add-on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- First add a plane, and subdivide it 4 or 5 times.
- Select a vertex close to the center, then grow the selection with
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> a few times (however large you want the circle to be), and switch to face
  selection with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> *>face*

This is where the *Loop tools add-on* comes in as mentioned in the comments. If you do not have it enabled already, enable it by opening *user preferences* with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> and searching for 'loop' under the add-ons tab:

[image]

- Press <kbd>W</kbd> for the specials menu, and choose *loop tools>
  circle* or just press <kbd>W</kbd> >  <kbd>L</kbd>  > <kbd>C</kbd>
  and <kbd>X</kbd>  to delete faces.
- Switch to *edge selection* with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> *>edge* and select the new edge loop where the faces
  were deleted, and enable *proportional edit* with <kbd>O</kbd>
- Translate along the Z axis with either linear or sharp falloff ( I used sharp in my example) until
  you are happy with how it looks.

As I said in the comments, the *decimate modifier* would be useful here. Add it set to *unsubdivide*  with 1 iteration to match the topology of your reference.

You can end up with something like the following:

[image]

Gif of the process:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **Screw** and **Decimate** modifiers to create this shape and others like it.

First, add a *Bezier Curve* and shape it like the slope of that volcano-ish shape.

[image]

Next, exit **Edit Mode** and add a **Screw** modifier. You can leave all of the options as the default for now, though if you want, you can disable the *Smooth Shading* option. To better view the mesh, switch into **Wireframe** mode in the viewport.

[image]

Next, add a **Subdivision Surface** modifier and leave the options as default for now.

[image]

Technically, this works fine. However, in the image you showed, the topology has two perpendicular edge loops running diagonally, while right now we have edge loops running horizontally and vertically. To fix this, add a **Decimate** modifier, set the type to *Un-Subdivide*, and set the *Iterations* to *1*.

[image]

Any of the above modifiers and/or curve can be tweaked to get the desired result. The most useful values would probably be the *Steps* in the **Screw** modifier, and the *Subdivisions* in the **Subdivision Surface** modifier.

Comment: Is there a way to make the volcano not circle shaped, and make the shape of the top and bottom end different?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking. "Make the shape" different in what way?

Comment: I think he means that in the reference image the base is square-ish with four apparent sides, not circular